# Why does window title get truncated? [Windows API]

Tags: python, winapi

I have looked at other similar questions and people were using different suffixes and it caused the error, but I don't see it anywhere in my code. Please tell me what is causing the problem.

This is what the window looks like, it doesn't display the whole window title, just the first word.

Let me add a few more words just so that Stack Overflow doesn't complain
[image]

```
from user32 import *

hInst = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(0)


def window_proc(hwnd: HWND, umsg: UINT, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT:
    if umsg == WindowMessage.DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        return 0
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam)


def create_window(className, windowName):
    wnd_main = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        className,
        windowName,
        WindowStyles.OVERLAPPED
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION
        | WindowStyles.SYSMENU
        | WindowStyles.THICKFRAME
        | WindowStyles.MINIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.MAXIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        600,
        600,
        0,
        0,
        hInst,
        0,
    )
    if not wnd_main:
        print("Window Creation Falid: ", GetLastError())
        return
    return wnd_main


def main():
    wclassName = "My"
    wname = "Left"
    wndClass = WNDCLASSEXW()
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW)
    wndClass.style = ClassStyles.HREDRAW | ClassStyles.VREDRAW
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WNDPROC(window_proc)
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0
    wndClass.hInstance = hInst
    wndClass.hIcon = 0
    wndClass.hCursor = 0
    wndClass.hBrush = windll.gdi32.GetStockObject(0)
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = 0
    wndClass.lpszClassName = wclassName
    wndClass.hIconSm = 0

    RegisterClassExW(byref(wndClass))

    wnd_main = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        wclassName,
        wname,
        WindowStyles.OVERLAPPED
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION
        | WindowStyles.SYSMENU
        | WindowStyles.THICKFRAME
        | WindowStyles.MINIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.MAXIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        600,
        600,
        0,
        0,
        hInst,
        0,
    )
    ShowWindow(wnd_main, 5)
    UpdateWindow(wnd_main)

    msg = MSG()
    lpmsg = pointer(msg)

    while (GetMessageW(lpmsg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0:
        TranslateMessage(lpmsg)
        DispatchMessageW(lpmsg)


main()
```

Comment: I would expect that behavior when passing a Unicode string to `CreateWindowExA()`, but not `CreateWindowExW()`

Comment: What module are you using? How do ensure that "from user32 import *" works?

Comment: this is user32.py that I wrote https://gist.github.com/aryan-debug/a37144e7bdad7b0814bc9602be9467e2

Comment: @AryanArora your declaration of `DefWindowProcW` is mapping to `user32.DefWindowProcA`, which is wrong, it should be mapped to `user32.DefWindowProcW` instead. So now your issue makes more sense. You are creating a Unicode window, but are using an ANSI message handler for it. So your window's title gets cut off at the first `0x00` byte in the Unicode string you are using for the title.

Comment: @i486 does Python even have macros?

Comment: @i486 you know this is a Python question?